# errors trying to insert into mysql database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

Unhandled error when I try to add to database? The OdbcParameterCollection only accepts non-null OdbcParameter type objects, not String objects.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    string email = TextBox1.Text; //added variable name
    string firstname = TextBox2.Text;
    string secondname = TextBox3.Text;
    string dob = TextBox4.Text;
    string location = TextBox5.Text;
    string aboutme = TextBox6.Text;

    OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite; User=root; Password=;");
    cn.Open();
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO User (Email, FirstName, SecondName, DOB, Location, Aboutme) VALUES (email, firstname, secondname, dob, location, aboutme)"); // fixed incomplete insert statement.

        cmd.Parameters.Add(email);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(firstname);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(secondname);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(dob);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(location);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(aboutme);//add the parameter to the command
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //actually run the sql


    }

}
```

I tryed this but I get the error System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

I also changed the database so it wasnt NN (non-null) to see if it would help but no joy

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Odbc;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    string email = TextBox1.Text; //added variable name
    string firstname = TextBox2.Text;
    string secondname = TextBox3.Text;
    string dob = TextBox4.Text;
    string location = TextBox5.Text;
    string aboutme = TextBox6.Text;

    OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite; User=root; Password=;");
    cn.Open();
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO User(Email) VALUES('?Email')");



    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("?email", email));
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


    }

}
```

The data in the database is capital letters like 'L'ocation and my strings are set to lower case. Not sure if its back to front in my code tho?

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- Table `gymwebsite`.`User`

-- -----------------------------------------------------

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gymwebsite`.`User` (

  `UserID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,

  `Email` VARCHAR(245) NULL ,

  `FirstName` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,

  `SecondName` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,

  `DOB` VARCHAR(15) NULL ,

  `Location` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,

  `Aboutme` VARCHAR(245) NULL ,

  PRIMARY KEY (`UserID`) )

ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `gymwebsite`.`user`
(`UserID`,
`Email`,
`FirstName`,
`SecondName`,
`DOB`,
`Location`,
`Aboutme`)
VALUES
(
{UserID: INT},
{Email: VARCHAR},
{FirstName: VARCHAR},
{SecondName: VARCHAR},
{DOB: VARCHAR},
{Location: VARCHAR},
{Aboutme: VARCHAR}
);
EDIT `gymwebsite`.`user`;
```

Comment: they were i tryed changing made no difference

Comment: I remember doing this with sql and I had to refrence each textbox in the values area is it possible to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO User (Email, FirstName, SecondName, DOB, Location, Aboutme) VALUES ("+ email +","+ firstname+","+SecondName+","+DOB+","+Location+","+Aboutme+")",cn);
```

Try to play using parameters..that i posted earlier and have it working.

Regards

Comment: try again i just edited my post..can you try to use a 1 column insert "INSERT INTO User(Email) VALUES('?Email')"; cmd.Parameters.Add("?Email",email);

Comment: [InvalidOperationException: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.]

Comment: I edit it gain. you forgot to place cn(your odbc connection) after the cmd.

Comment: ok yaayyyyy no errors but we have another problem lol (and super well spotted on the cn at the end! Had everyone stumped! But the other problem is its only entering ?Email into the table rather than the input i put into textbox1?

Comment: nope I get an error if i try that maybe if i change ?email to textbox in the values like when u use ms sql?

Comment: Parameters are case Sensitive. ?Email not ?email in what you declare in your insert statement."INSERT INTO User (Email) VALUES (?Email)"

Comment: in my database its Email in my string email = textbox its lowercase so i can distinguish between the string and the query entity, so how should right it?

Comment: nope for some reason I still get the error if I remove the quotes from '?Email' in the values statement? If i put "?email" in the cmd.param it makes no difference

Comment: '?Email' save ?Email in db(Mistake). "INSERT INTO User (Email) VALUES (?Email)" then use  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Email",email);

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Email)' at line 1

Comment: yeah I get that error when I try that! is there a way to change Values (?email) to something like ('+ textbox1.text +') ?

Comment: Yup... "INSERT INTO User (Email) VALUES ("+ textbox1.text +")"..and remove cmd.parameters.

Comment: OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO User (Email) VALUES ('"+ TextBox1.Text +"')", cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Email", email);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: hahah damm u beat me to it i got it tho woop!! Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: haha..i dont know you are having an error bout cmd.parameters but still try to play with that. I will edit my post and mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Specify all of the parameters on this line -

> `var v1 =
>   cmd.Parameters.Add("email",OdbcType.VarChar,
>   , 30);` `v1.Value  = email;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `OdbcParameter` instances to the parameter collection:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("email", email)); 
...
```

The first parameter is the name of the parameter in your insert statement, and the second is an object used to determine `DbType` and content.

Answer (score 0):

You might also have to swtich your SQL command to use question marks like:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO User (Email, FirstName, SecondName, DOB, Location, Aboutme) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

`cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter(email));`

There's a few overloads too.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Parameters.AddWithValue()** method,

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO `User` 
  (Email, FirstName, SecondName, DOB, Location, Aboutme) 
    VALUES 
     ('?Email', '?FirstName', '?SecondName', '?DOB', '?Location','?Aboutme')",cn); 

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?Email", textBox1.Text);
...
```

Comment: does this mean I dont need the strings?

Comment: same again i get ?email in place of the text from texbox